# Using hardcoded data instead of CSV file in D3 graphs

Tags: d3.js

Although I'm quite familiar with javasript.
For the first time I'm using D3 and example svg graph: http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1

in the example above, CSV file is used as data. (the file from example is aster_data.csv)

I want to use data array defined within the script instead of the file.

Instead of:

```
d3.csv('aster_data.csv', function(error, data) {
...
```

I've added my array-

```
var myData= [
      {"id":"ABC","order":1,"score":50,"weight":1,"color":"#9E0041","label": "Line1"},
      {"id":"CDE","order":2,"score":60,"weight": 1,"color":"#C32F4B", "label": "Line2"}
];
d3.selection(myData, function(error, data) {
...
```

However it doesn't work, not I can't see any errors in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `selection`.  The `csv` function fetches the csv, then calls the lambda with the corresponding data.  Just call the body of that lambda with your data in the `data` variable.

```
var data= [
  {"id":"ABC","order":1,"score":50,"weight":1,"color":"#9E0041","label": "Line1"},
  {"id":"CDE","order":2,"score":60,"weight": 1,"color":"#C32F4B", "label": "Line2"}
];

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.id     =  d.id;
    d.order  = +d.order;
    d.color  =  d.color;
    d.weight = +d.weight;
    d.score  = +d.score;
    d.width  = +d.weight;
    d.label  =  d.label;
  });
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I got your point. I thought about it too. The problem is that: d3.csv('aster_data.csv', function(error, data) {..}.  introduces 'data', which is used in statements within {} So I can't simply comment it out and I'm not sure how to nest statement following after.